# hiding text if no data found in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I am leveraging vuejs to pull data into my project. I have this simple request of waiting to hide the Certification text if I have no data in the v-for. IS there a super easy way to achieve this?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<p style="text-align:left;"> <strong>Certification:</strong> <span v-for="certification in getCertText(selectedJob)" href="#" v-on:click="updateCertfication(certification)"  >{{certification}} </span></p></br>
```

Comment: is `getCertText` returning an array?

Comment: Yes if it exists

Comment: Does it return an empty array if nothing exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if array is empty.

```
 <strong v-if="getCertText(selectedJob).length > 0">Certification:</strong>
```

This should work